# Should security of application be configured before testing the entire application?

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, testing, e-commerce

I have a Spring MVC application. I have not automated the testing process. I have also not secured the application.
My Question is what should I do First?

- Should I configure the security of my application?

or

- Should I start testing my Spring MVC Web Application and developing test cases?

Comment: What would be your reason to test an unsecured application? I assume it will _never_ be used in that state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Securing systems or applications (hardening) is bound to unexpectedly break functionality. Therefore you always need to test after hardening.

On the other hand, if something does not work after hardening, how do you know for certain it is because of the hardening and not because of something else?

In other words, you need to do both. Test before securing the application, and test again after securing the application. If time and resources are limited you should try to find a balance regarding the extent of the testing before and after.

EDIT: If testing is done using production data, and user authentication and authorization as well as controlling access to this production data is of great importance, then first test the hardening and internal security of the application independently before letting other users test the application. Indeed this means that perhaps only a limited amount of trusted users can do functional testing before the securing of the application has taken place.

Answer (score 1):

Security testing never finds everything.

Therefore, you should secure your application as much as possible, prior to testing it.

Never use the security testing results as a way of generating a "lock down list". Build in security from the start, securing it as much as possible from what you already know about.

When you believe you are ready, run some security scans to find the gaps.

And I would always recommend hiring an external company at the end in order to pentest it to find the things you never thought about.